# Angular 2 combine two EventEmitters

Tags: javascript, angular, eventemitter

I am making an app with Angular 2 where i have two components each having its own EventEmitter. One EventEmitter is fired when bunch of checkboxes are checked/unchecked and the other is fired when a search keyword is entered. The search bar is in the header component and the checkboxes are in different component.

I am able to catch these `eventEmitters` separately - however i want to combine their data into URL params.

For example:
`http://localhost:4200;data=a123,b345,c678;q=searchkeyword`

The data values should come from checkboxes and the `q` from a search bar.

I cant seem to find a way to append to the URL params data and keyword provided separately.

Can someone please suggest to me how i should do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you need to wait for both events will be fired I would suggest to use observable . with the zip operator:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Comment: Well, both events can fire on different times. But they need to not override each other. One event sends the `data` values while the other sends `searchkeyword`. I need to build the URL based on their values.

For example, if i check two checkboxes, the url will change. Then later on i enter a keyword in the search field, that too should be appended in the URL (not overriding the values set by checkboxes). I hope this makes the question little more clear :)

Comment: So the use of observables is exactly what you need.
make observable for ant event you want to listren to,
subscribe to all the events with merge operator.
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html
merge will fit you better then zip.